# Export tables to image in python?

Tags: python, image, formatting

I am working on my thesis currently. I would like to represent a variety of descriptive statistics in a nicely formatted table. Preferably, I could export the table to an image so I do not have to take a screenshot. I have attached an images that shows how I envision the end product to look like. Kind regards. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLEce.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of python modules to help you do this sort of thing, but pretty much they all use `matplotlib` under the hood to create figures you can use to save to a png or other file.  Thus, you can do something like this:

```
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()

  # set the size
  fig.set_dpi(150)
  fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

  # optional put in a background image
  ax.imshow(grapharray, vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, cmap=cmap)

  # add text at each point
  for x in data:
    for y in data[x]:
      ax.text(y, x, f"{data[x][y]}",
              ha="center", va="center", color="r")
```

I'll end with a caveat that PNG images in a table is the least ideal way to go, but it does work and I've done it.  SVGs or something else that scales well is better, but encoding into the raw final document format is best.

You'll need to mess with scaling, font sizes, etc to get it to look right.